# How to slice a pandas DataFrame between two dates (day/month) ignoring the year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a pandas DataFrame with DatetimeIndex for multiple years between the 15th of april and the 16th of september. Afterwards I want to set a value the mask.

I was hoping for a function similar to [`between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), but this doesn't exist.

My actual solution is a loop over the unique years.

### Minimal Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'target':0}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2022-01-01', freq='H'))

start_date = "04-15"
end_date = "09-16"
for year in df.index.year.unique():
    # normal approche
    # df[f'{year}-{start_date}':f'{year}-{end_date}'] = 1

    # similar approche slightly faster
    df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(f'{year}-{start_date}'):df.index.get_loc(f'{year}-{end_date}')+1]=1
```

Does a solution exist where I can avoid the loop and maybe improve the performance?

Answer (score 2):

To get the dates between April 1st and October 31st, what about using the month?

```
df.loc[df.index.month.isin(range(4, 10)), 'target'] == 1
```

If you want to map any date/time, just ignoring the year, you can replace the year to 2000 (leap year) and use:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2000-%m-%d'))
df.loc[(s >= '2000-04-15') & (s <= '2020-09-16'), 'target'] = 1
```

Comment: This is working, if I want the complete april and september, but what happens if I start at the 15th of april?

Comment: Not the most straightforward, but see update

Comment: This could be a working approche if I reset the index afterwards. I have to think about this solution.

Comment: You don't need to modify the index, as this is using boolean indexing. It will even work from a column (just use `df['col'].dt.strftime` in this case)

Comment: I like your idea, but there is a downside. To reduce the runtime I normally use `iloc` instead of `loc` like in `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('2020-03-01 00:00'):df.index.get_loc('2020-04-01 00:00')+1]=1`. But this isn't possible in the new approche, because the time isn't chronological anymore.

Comment: @mosc9575 my approach does not alter the relative order of the rows, if it's initially chronological it will remain that way